# Can secondary routing priority model and status based capacity model work at the same time for Case routing via Omnichannel?

Tags: servicecloud, omnichannel, service-console

So currently I have setup a Queue based routing of Email-to-Case along with using Omnichannel feature. Agents(Queue members) are automatically assigned the case. Each agent is assigned 1 Case at a time. Now by switching on Status Based Capacity model- I'm able to wipe off the cases from the Omnichannel widget only when the Case Status is set to Closed. Without switching on this Capacity model, closed cases won't get disappeared from the widget by default which looks like an unexpected behaviour. Now I have another requirement to route High Priority Cases to the Agent first. For this I think I can do it through Secondary Priority model. But when I configured this model, the Cases with High priority are not getting routed to agent first.

So my question is how I can make sure that Cases with High Priority get routed to agent at first while also wiping off cases which get closed from Omnichannel widget?